# ¿Como unificar palabras que son lo mismo pero estan escritas diferente?

Tags: python

Para un programa necesito meter valores de un fichero en una lista.

Lo que pasa es que hay palabras como *Real-Madrid*, real madrid, madrid, etc... que como son todas la misma debería aparecer solo una vez, pero al compararlo en python, `a == b`, me da que son diferentes porque están escritas de manera distinta.

No se si sabeis de alguna forma para que me detecte que deberían ser lo mismo.

Comment: Antes que te haces la pregunta como implementar la comparación, tienes que decidir como consideras la igualdad. Si consideras que _Real-Madrid_ es lo mismo que _real madrid_ y _madrid_, eso significa también que _Real_ es lo mismo que _madrid_? Que es tu formato de referencia?

Comment: Es que no son lo mismo. "real madrid" son dos palabras y "madrid" es mucho más que un equipo de fútbol. Por poder ser, podría ser también una ciudad de México o un apellido. O especificas mejor qué necesitas o no será posible darte una respuesta que te sirva de algo.

Answer (score 1):

Podrías buscar buscar la palabra dentro de la cadena, por ejemplo:

```
words = ["Real Madrid", "Real-Madrid", "madrid", "Other Word"]
selectedWord = "madrid"

for word in words:
    result = word.lower().find(selectedWord)
    print result
```

obtendrías este resultado:

```
5
5
0
-1
```

Compara cada elemento en la lista con la palabra elegida y retorna la posición, en caso no este esta en el String retorna -1, para evitar las mayúsculas y minúsculas se usa lower().

Answer (score 1):

Hay una función interna de Python para eso: [difflib](https://docs.python.org/2/library/difflib.html).

```
from difflib import SequenceMatcher

def similar(a, b):
    return SequenceMatcher(None, a, b).ratio()

similar("Real Madrid", "Real-Madrid")
0.9090909090909091

similar("Real Madrid", "RealMadrid")
0.9523809523809523

similar("Real Madrid", "Madrid")
0.7058823529411765

similar("Real Madrid", "Salamanca")
0.3
```